# translate animation lag

Tags: android, animation

In my app  i'm creating 20-30 views each view have 2 image views and on runtime i'm showing images from res folder to respective imageview . i have added gesture listener on each view and every fling motion i want to swipe a view . for swipe i'm using translate animation but sometimes translate animation takes much time and there a lag in animation. i have also check the heap size it takes 11-12 mb on galaxy s2 (4.0.4) . also have made bitmaps purgable still there  a lag with view  so is there any trick to fast animation and remove lag ???

Comment: What size is your images in px?

Comment: @Warpzit image size 221*279 but i'm doing downsampling before using image

Comment: you could try to add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" under the application tag of the manifest.

Comment: Try to experiment with simpler layout and see if you can make it run smooth with less (fx only 1-5 views). Just to figure out if the problem is caused by something else than overload.